# How could i easily disable login popup at google chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiLsO.png)

Once someone showed me a very small piece of code for hiding this popup. The bad part of the story is that I forgot what kind of code it was and my computer hasnt saved it.

Do someone know which small code/word it has been?

I'll already tried to change my securityConfig (csrf().disable()), but it doesnt work. Also tried to changed my UseEffect in my UserContext at Frontend:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   
    if (!userContext.isAuthenticated) {
      navigate('/login'); 
    }
  }, []);
```

But I think its a backend thing to solve. Grateful for any help

This is my SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return Argon2PasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_8();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
        String organizationPath = "/api/organization/**";

        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, organizationPath).hasRole(Role.ADMIN.toString())
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, organizationPath).hasRole(Role.ADMIN.toString())
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, organizationPath).hasRole(Role.ADMIN.toString())
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, organizationPath).hasAnyRole("BASIC", "ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you provided, I assume this is a basic [HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication)

So to remove it you need to update your backend code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added my SecurityConfig File above. What do I have to change there now?

Comment: You can try to remove ".httpBasic().and()" and if it doesn't help - also try to remove ".authorizeHttpRequests()"

Comment: removing ".httpBasic().and()" was the solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JustRob I'm happy that it works for you! Can I ask you to mark this answer as correct (green check mark) ?

Comment: Okay it seems like I've only looked at the old version of my project, when I tested your solution. The popup was away, but I couldn't use my login anymore..do you maybe have any others ideas left?

Comment: @JustRob I still think that removing ".httpBasic().and()" or ".authorizeHttpRequests()" may be a solution. But if not - you can compare the old file (which has no authorization) and the new file (which has authorization) and check the difference.